# Meteor change collection detail(document Values) before DOM reacts in template helper

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am implementing a grid System called pricing in which I have collection called pricing. What I want to do is change pricing collection schema before binding it to DOM. I want to make a new object from
 `Pricing.find({})` 
so that it will be easy for me to manipulate it in template. It should also be reactive  like normally a collection is.

**Pricing.js**

```
Template.pricing.helpers({
    pricing:Pricing.find({}),
    publlisherIs: function (publisher) {
        return this.publisher === publisher;
    }
});
```

**Pricing.html**

```
 <table class="table">
               <thead>
                <th class="col-md-1">Ask</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">Bid</th>
                <th class="col-md-1">Close</th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               {{#each pricing}}
                   {{#if publlisherIs "GVM"}}
                       <tr data-id="{{ _id }}">
                           <!--<div class="col-md-2"> {{contract}}</div>-->
                           {{#each price}}
                               <td class=" price-input" data-price="{{type}}"><input  id="item_to_add" size="8" value="{{value}}" type="text"></td>
                           {{/each}}
                       </tr>
                   {{/if}}
               {{/each}}
               </tbody>
           </table>
```

Now my Pricing single document schema is like this

```
{
  "_id" : "kSqH7QydFnPFHQmQH",
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-10-11T11:49:50.241Z"),
  "contractId" : "X5zTJ2y675PjmaLMx",
  "contract" : "wwwer",
  "price" : [{
      "type" : "ask",
      "value" : "4"
    }, {
      "type" : "bid",
      "value" : 0
    }, {
      "type" : "close",
      "value" : 0
    }],
  "publisher" : "GVM"
}
```

Comment: Does [Mongo,Collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) or [Collection.find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)'s transform argument or [cursor.map](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/map)?

Comment: I didn't get your question.

Comment: It was supposed to be: Do Mongo,Collection or Collection.find's transform argument or cursor.map do what you intend? :)

Comment: Collection.find's and then change collections attribute